# what is the need to create .babelrc in preact application

Tags: preact

I am starting with Preact application. the [documentation](https://github.com/developit/preact) says

**Instead of declaring the @jsx pragma in your code, it's best to configure it globally in a** `.babelrc`:

For Babel 5 and prior:

```
{ "jsxPragma": "h" }
```

For Babel 6:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-react-jsx", { "pragma":"h" }]
  ]
}
```

I am new to Preact world and wants to understand why do we need to create this file & what is jsx pragma ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pragma is a comment (`/** @jsx h */` here) placed on the top of a file containing some JSX, telling the JSX transformer which function you want to call to create each element of you virtual dom. Preact uses [hyperscript](https://github.com/hyperhype/hyperscript), that's why you need to use the `h` pragma. Preact suggest to create this file so babel take care of the pragma itself, without you needing to add it to every file. This way you can't forget to put it on a file.

You suggest you to read [WTF is JSX](https://jasonformat.com/wtf-is-jsx/), which is a fundamental post if you want to know everything about JSX.